# Highlight the row in excel mac 2011 when a cell has a specific word

Tags: macos, excel, formatting, conditional-statements, row

In Excel 2011 Mac (it seems to be important since other referenced solutions in stackoverflow for excel windows or mac older versions don't seem to work).

I want to apply conditional formatting so when a cell in column D includes a word "student" the full row which includes the cell gets a color format (blue color for the text white/empty filling for the cell).

I have tried INDIRECT and some other formulas but I don't get it right. Only the cell that includes the word gets the formatting, not the whole row (that is, the rest of the cells on the same row where the pattern matches).

Answer (score 8):

Admittedly, this answer is based on the Windows version but it should still work for you.
*(Pictures taken from mix of Windows and Mac versions where possible.)*

1. Select **Manage Rules...** from the **Conditional Formatting** menu.

   [image: Conditional Formatting menu]
2. Click the **New Rule...** button.

   [image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager]
3. Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**, enter the formula as shown below, and then click the **Format...** button to choose your conditional format (blue text with no fill).
   *- You said you were looking for the word "student" in column D, and I have assumed that row 3 is the first row that you want this conditional formatting to be applied. Just change the **3** to another row number if this is not the case.*

   [image: New Formatting Rule]

   **If the word "student" is not the only thing in your target cell, then use the following formula instead:**
   `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("student",$D3))`
4. Then type a range into the **Applies to** textbox as shown.
   *- In this example, we assume that row 3 is the first row and row 400 is the last row that you want the conditional formatting to be applied to.*
   *- Note that we did not include column letters in the formula since we want every column of each row to be included.*

   [image: Conditional Formatting Rules Manager with New Rule]
5. Click **OK** and you should be done.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: First of all, big thanks. That worked when I changed =$2:$400 . First "Student" was on D3 and somehow having $3 would jynx everything, random lines would be highlighted, changing to $2 made all "Student" work.

Comment: Another small question. If I have "Student, PostDoc" the formula won't highlight Student or the row. If I change to "*student*" in the rule field it doesn't work either. Is there any way to match and highlight an "Student" row when there are more words in the cell?

Comment: @NoImporta See my edit under the picture for step 3. Using `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("student",$D3))` will search the target cell for the word "student" even if it's not the only thing there. ([As shown here](http://i.imgur.com/3xaW7.png))

Comment: @lakovosioan Some functions don't work because it's excel 2011 mac in spanish and they translated some of the functions but not all. I tried the equivalent in spanish to isnumber and search and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @NoImporta It should technically still work even if you only use `=SEARCH("student",$D3)`. This takes advantage of the way numbers are translated into boolean expressions.

Comment: @lakovosian yeah ISNUMBER should filter the numbers out and SEARCH would find in the text but it doesn't work. it turns out you can't add the = to the formula definition, you just type ISNUMBER(SEARCH("student",$D3)) and then it "works" but nothing gets filtered, not with the isnumber, search combo or with search alone... Is there a way to apply the one that I got working to the full book, not just one sheet? my book is composed of 20 sheets or so but conditional formatting seems to work only on a sheet not when i select several.

Comment: I'm going crazy now.  
Let's say I have several data sheets with 4 columns (A,B,C,D) and about 300 rows. I want to highlight every row which includes "Student" in D cell. It should work with "Student PostDoc" aswell.  
If I use conditional formatting and I "Use a formula to decide..." I add any of those mentioned without the " and with single colon because " doesn't find anything. It doesn't find the right ones, just random others(bachelor) but never "student". And somehow If I used $D="student" that worked but as only as long as I put in formula $D3 ("student") and $D2 as where to apply to.

Comment: I think you have to copy the conditional formatting over to each sheet individually - just because of the way Excel handles them.

Comment: Thanks, very clear! Worked well for me "out of the box" on Mac OS X Excel v14.5.3

Answer (score -2):

Follow these steps for conditional formatting.

Step 1 - Select **Conditional Formatting** > **New Rule...**

Step 2 - Select **Style** Dropdown

Step 3 - Choose **Classic**

[Step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN1kD.png) - Select Dropdown with **Format only top or bottom ranked values**

Step 5 - Select from Dropdown **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**

[Step 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1TiM.png) - Highlight desired Cells and take note of the current cell. (D3)

Step 7 - Use formula: **=MATCH("Student",D3,0)** in the formula section.
 Again, D3 is the current cell.

Step 8 - Press **OK**